# VS Debugger is not working properly

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, debugging, sharepoint-2010

When I trying to debug my code in Visual Studio, the debugger firing properly, but when I hit on F11 it will comes to next line and in the next hitting the same key, it goes to the previous step. And another problem is that, in my code i am checking one condition in the if loop. I am appending my piece of code here

```
SPListItemCollection coll = oList.GetItems(query);

if (coll != null && coll.Count > 0)
{
   spManualLstItem = coll[0];
}
```

In my case the Coll will return the count as `1`. But while debugging, the debugger shows it's `0` and it will enters to the loop. I don't know whats happening with Visual Studio? Did you guys experienced this phenomenon?

Comment: Could you have more than one thread running this section of code at once, that would explain the "going to the previous step" part.

Comment: No. Only one instance is running at a time. Recently i have restarted the machine again. But the problem still there.

Comment: Try rebuilding the solution.May be the debugger is running with the symbols generated from old code